# Laptop halts on not yet low battery

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, battery

Two years old samsung laptop with Windows 8.1 64 bit halts without notice or taking low battery action. I realized that it happens when it shows some 55% battery limit. It dies suddenly and immediatelly. I wonder if

- the problem is that battery charge level is incorrectly detected and in fact it is 0% already
- it dies though it has 55% yet.

One more thing - it occurs 15 minutes since I unplug the AC power cord. Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notebook powers off way before battery is on a critical level](http://superuser.com/questions/643628/notebook-powers-off-way-before-battery-is-on-a-critical-level)

Comment: You are right that symptoms are similar. But why does it fail after 15 minutes? It must have enough energy yet, so even if the detection is wrong it shall continue to run. And when I turned it on again, it halts again, so there is really no energy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely a broken battery. Do you know anyone that has the same model of laptop as yours? Without replacing it with a spare it's hard to determine if it's a software or hardware problem, but in my experience the symptoms that you have listed lead to a malfunctioning battery.

Comment: No, I do not have. I think I will have to buy new battery to test it.

Comment: I found test battery feature in BIOS and the notebook was switched off in 15 minutes when it was on 60% level. So you will be right. PS I am about to delete this question because of downvotes. Nevertheless thank you.

Comment: I gave an upvote. I don't think it's a bad question :)

Comment: Thanks. That duplicate question was not offered when I was writing the question. There were others and I read them all.

Comment: Solved. I bought new battery and notebook gets hibernated when it is less than 10% capacity remaining. On the other hand this battery can power only one hour and 45 minutes though it claims 5 kWAh capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue happening when you are actively using the machine or if you leave it for some time?

You might want to check your Power options in Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Power Options > Edit Plan Settings or "Change when the computer sleeps".

Check to see what time your machine is set to go to sleep when it is off the battery.

If this is not the case, as advised from the previous comment, it might be worth trying to find an identical charger and see if this resolves the problem.

Comment: No, I use the laptop. It is not sleep mode. I tried to increase the limits in power options but let it sleep at 55%?!